# How to get google contact list using artdarek-oauth-4-laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am using artdarek-oauth-4-laravel for the Login to my website via Facebook, twitter and google.

Login part is working fine. But I want to get some more data from these api, like if user is registering through the google then I am looking for their general info as well as google contact list, or if the user is registering from Facebook then I am trying to get the /me and /friend-list etc.

Here, I am just taking the case of google.

I have set the config like this

```
   'Google' => array(
        'client_id'     => '***********************************',
        'client_secret' => '***********************************',
        'scope'         => array('userinfo_email', 'userinfo_profile', 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/'),
    ),
```

My Controller Function is this:-

```
   public function loginWithGoogle()
   {
       $code = Input::get( 'code' );

       $googleService = OAuth::consumer( 'Google' );
       if ( !empty( $code ) )
       {
          $token = $googleService->requestAccessToken( $code );
      //  $result = json_decode( $googleService->request( 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo' ), true );
          $result = json_decode( $googleService->request( 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full' ), true );
          echo json_encode($result);

       }
       else {
         // get googleService authorization
         $url = $googleService->getAuthorizationUri();
         // return to google login url
         return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
       }
   }
```

This code leads me to the google api and asks for all the permission that I have set in the scope of the service. Here once I got the access token after exchanging the code parameter with the api, I am calling the url to return me the contact list but it fails. And I am getting this message from the laravel :-Failed to request resource.

If I call the commented $result request, it returns me the result.

So, I wanted to know how can we use this library for the data other than login and register. In case of retrieving facebook friendlist the same thing happens but the login works. (My Facebook App has the permission to get friendlist).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any solution? For me $result is actually NULL.

Comment: Yes the problem was with the permission to the APP that I have created on google. Once I have assigned the 'Contacts API' permissions to the app (On Google API from here https://console.developers.google.com), it started giving me the contact list.

Answer (score 1):

Check this response, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26488136/434790.

It worked for me. The culprit: `alt=json` to be added to `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full`